# Desktop is visible after suspend

Tags: suspend, gnome-shell, lock-screen, 18.10

After upgrade to Ubuntu 18.10 I have noticed a strange behavior.

When I close the lid on my notebook, it goes in to suspend, as expected. But, when I am returning from suspend the desktop is visible, with all the programs that were latest used, opened.

To return from this state I have to lock the screen (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and then log in again, using my password.

The behavior is similar to [bug#1532508](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1532508), but the difference is that in my case the information stays visible after I open the lid on my notebook.

Is this an know issue/bug and are there any fix for this problem?

Comment: Problem solved over night... after I did a upgrade.

Comment: Unfortunately, for me the problem persists. After waking up, the old screen contents are visible, but flickering - and I can't click on anything except the pause symbol in the upper right corner. Then the system goes to sleep, and after waking it up again, everything is as it should be.

Comment: I have the same exact issue since I have updated to 18.10

Comment: I have this issue to on 18.10 it also does not seem to respond to any action.

Comment: It looks like its a ages old problem, started 2011 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/830348. Not solved till yet. Why?!