# Ubuntu 20.04 briefly displays screen contents when waking up

Tags: 20.04, suspend

I am new to Ubuntu/Linux

I just purchased a brand new Dell Precision 7550 with Ubuntu 20.04

I have set my account to ask for a password when waking up. When the system wakes up, it displays the full contents on the screen for 2 seconds before hiding the screen and asking for the password.

I am not used to this behavior in either Windows systems or Mac OS systems, where the screen goes directly to the lock screen upon waking up.

I am guessing there is some setting that I can use to have the Ubuntu machine wake up and NOT display the contents of the screen before showing the lock screen.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: This is a known bug that has been present for a very long time. See [Launchpad Bug # 1280300](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1280300). Also see this question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1085426/100356. I highly recommend creating an account on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) and [marking yourself as impacted](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1280300/+affectsmetoo) so the developers will prioritize this bug (because it affects so many people) and fix it.

Comment: It's not just you; happens to me as well.  (Though not on every Ubuntu machine I use...so there is something different between them, but I don't know what it is since they were all set up the same way.)  I have multiple workspaces and as a "workaround", I go to an empty one before locking my screen...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Xorg, it may help to switch to Wayland.

According to [comment #19 of Launchpad Bug 1280300](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1280300/comments/19)...

> X11 [...] is the major reason why screen locking will never work reliably as long as we haven't switched to Wayland [...].

I just did a few quick tests in Ubuntu 24.01.

- The issue was present when using Xorg.
- But the problem went away when I switched to Wayland.

To use Wayland on Ubuntu 24.04 [follow these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1258280/100356):

1. Execute:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-session-wayland
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

   Ensure the following line is commented as shown:

   ```
   #WaylandEnable=false
   ```
3. Edit `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules`

   Comment out all lines (i.e. make sure *each* line begins with a `#` symbol).
4. Execute:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart gdm3
   ```
5. On the GDM Login screen, click your user name
6. Before entering the password, click on the gear icon at the bottom right corner of the screen
7. Select "Ubuntu on Wayland"
8. Enter your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Subsequent logins will automatically log you into the Wayland session, so you do not need to repeat these steps again (unless you switch to Xorg).